# Tokenize returns a vector that contains the delimiters - C++

Tags: c++, vector, tokenize

I have the function that tokenizes a vector string and returns without the delimiters. But, I want to return with delimiters.

Desired output:
`tokenize("<ab><>cd<", "<>")`

- should display: "<", "ab", ">", "<", ">", "cd", "<"

Here's my function:

```
vector<string> tokenize1(const string& s, const string& delim) {

vector<string> tokens;

string::size_type lastPos = s.find_first_not_of(delim, 0);
string::size_type pos = s.find_first_of(delim, lastPos);

while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
    tokens.push_back(s.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
    lastPos = s.find_first_not_of(delim, pos);
    pos = s.find_first_of(delim, lastPos);
}

return tokens;

}
```

Comment: By definition a tokenize function discards the separators. What you are trying to do is something else. What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure *why* you'd want to do this, but you've got almost all the code to do it already. Here's a minor modification that alternates between stuffing individual delimiter characters into the token vector (simpler if you're happy to return delimiter chunks, eg. `"><>"` instead of `"<", ">", "<"`) and adding whole non-delimiter chunks to it.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize2(const std::string& s, const std::string& delim)
{
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;

  auto nextDelimiter = s.find_first_of(delim, 0);
  auto nextNonDelimiter = s.find_first_not_of(delim, 0);

  while (std::string::npos != nextDelimiter || std::string::npos != nextNonDelimiter)
  {
    if (nextNonDelimiter > nextDelimiter)
    {
      for (auto d = nextDelimiter; d < nextNonDelimiter && d < s.size(); d++)
        tokens.push_back(s.substr(d, 1));

      nextDelimiter = s.find_first_of(delim, nextNonDelimiter);
    }
    else
    {
      tokens.push_back(s.substr(nextNonDelimiter, nextDelimiter - nextNonDelimiter));
      nextNonDelimiter = s.find_first_not_of(delim, nextDelimiter);
    }
  }

  return tokens;
}
```

Note the use of `auto` (because we're living in the future now) and `std::` (because `using namespace std;` is considered bad practise, for good reason).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right, we should be using auto from now on.